# Underscore.js - find a value of an object key using regexp?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I get an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var collection = [
  {
    name: 'hello',
    color: 'blue'
  },
  {
    name: 'world',
    color: 'brown'
  }, .... {thousands more}
];
```

What would be the proper way to use underscore to find out if *any* of the objects in the array has a value for the 'name' key equal to some regular expression?

`_.contains(collection, '/goodbye/i');  <-- this won't work ->`

How to tell it to use the 'name' key for searching?

Answer (score 11):

You could do:

```
filter = function (collection, key, regex) {
    return _.filter(collection, function(obj){ return obj[key].match(regex);});
};
```